# Is it possible to make a footnote inside the cut into the text

Tags: footnotes, memoir

Is it possible to make a footnote inside the text like in the image? If so, how? I’ve no MWE.

I’m using the `memoir` class.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Typically questions need to involve more than just posting an image of the desired output, although in this case I understand your dilemma if you truly don't know where to start. Unfortunately this kind of layout is very difficult to do in LaTeX. The closest potential for a solution might be to use the never-released `pullquote` package. See [Two-column text with circular insert](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/53073).

Comment: If having the notes cut into text is not a requirement, it is possible to have left and right margin notes, but not attached to the same paragraph. See [Margin notes on both left and right?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/101553).

Comment: @AlanMunn hello, yeah, i know. i had doubts about posting this... it´s really complicated and i trully don´t know where to start from. i´ll have a look at the suggestion you gave me in the first comment. for that i am very grateful. the thing is that i don´t want to use margin notes on left & right. i´m designing a book layout aimed at saving white space on the page and this type of notes reduce the blank space while making the page dynamic. this is something easy to do in photoshop, but my entire project is based on latex.

Comment: Tiny quibble about the title: "next" should be "text".  (Will make more sense.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please provide always a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your questions of how far you can go, at least to avoid us make the example of the solution from scratch

This approach use the `wrapfig` package to make the text cuts. However, note that a wrapfigure have several constraints, so it cannot be placed anywhere without care and expect a good result. See the manual of the package.

The MWE:

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{1}
\def\smark{\textsuperscript{(\textbf{\alph{foo}})}\addtocounter{foo}{1} } 
\def\thesidenote{{\bfseries\alph{foo}}} 
\def\notestyle{\footnotesize\sffamily{\thesidenote]} }
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{wrapfig} \intextsep0em \columnsep1em
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][2-3]
\lipsum[5][1-3] % Place it at the end of line o before the paragraph.
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{r}[1cm]{3cm} 
\begin{tabular}{;{1pt/1pt}p{3cm}}
\notestyle\lipsum[1][1] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3][1-2]\smark{}
\lipsum[3][3-8]

\lipsum*[2][1-5] 
\begin{wrapfigure}[4    ]{l}[1cm]{5cm}
\begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm};{1pt/1pt}}
\notestyle \lipsum[12][1-4]
\end{tabular}

\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3][1-3]\smark
\lipsum[4][1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'v never seen a tabular with something like `;{1pt/1pt}`, what does it do?

Comment: The vertical dashed line. Need the package  `arydshln` to work.

Comment: +1 While I agree that a MWE is usually appropriate, I think in this particular case, it wouldn't have helped much at all. It would at best have provided 4 lines of code, since the OP really didn't know where to start. So your admonishment is perhaps a bit harsh in this case.

Comment: @cfr Oh, I forgot to delete those packages. Edited, thanks.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, but because that, it was not just a comment, but a comment for the next question, with an answer. `;)`

Comment: I already +1ed ;). Thanks for editing.