# Vertical dashed lines (inside and outside of tables) in PlainTex / OpTex

Tags: plain-tex, optex

Taking an idea from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/696130/258453), what if I want to make a vertical dashed line in PlainTex or (preferably) Optex? I know I can use `\dotfill` in the text (horizontally), but how can I use it vertically in the text or in a table? One solution for running text would be to do the following (modifying Udi Fogiel's suggestion from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106358/264024))

```
\def\dotvfill{\par\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\vfill}

\vbox to 3cm{\dotvfill}

\bye
```

But what about tables? For example, if I want to change the vertical rules in this table to vertical dots?

```
\table{|ll|}{ \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106358/264024) answer your question?

Comment: @UdiFogiel, thanks, it did solve the issue in the text, see edit.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  to use a similar construction instead of a box rule?

Comment: @UdiFogiel, see edit.

Comment: your table preamble has three columns, while the table content has two. Is this intentional?

Comment: @UdiFogiel, you're right, corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the height of all lines in the table are equal, you can set `\vodotfil` for the vertical lines by a `\vbox` with given height. For example

```
\newdimen\bskip  \bskip=\baselineskip
\def\vdotfil{\lower.4\bskip\vbox to1.2\bskip{\leaders\vbox{\kern.5pt\hbox{.}\kern.5pt}\vfil}}

\table{(\vdotfil)ll(\vdotfil)}{ \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
   data & data \crl
}

\bye
```

But if the height of table lines aren't equal then the solution will be more complicated, because the expandable `\vrule` inside the `\hbox` cannot be simply replaced by `\ledares`.

Comment: It's great, but if I don't use horizontal lines (that is, if I only use `\cr` instead of `\crl`), the first and last dots in each line overlap.

Comment: @user574859 replace the height of the vbox in the definition of `\vdotfill` to `1.1\bskip`, i.e. `\def\vdotfil{\lower.4\bskip\vbox to1.1\bskip{\leaders\vbox{\kern.5pt\hbox{.}\kern.5pt}\vfil}}`

Comment: @UdiFogiel, thank you. Almost there. Although there is a weird vertical skip that I cannot remove even with `\thistable{\tablinespace=0pt}`. Depending on how I change `X\bskip`, there are weird clusters of balls. In this particular instance, I resolved it with `\vbox to 1.4\bskip`.